# Two img next to each other floated dont go next line

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/sV36r/

```
<div id="a"><div style="max-width: 350px;"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5b/Ultraviolet_image_of_the_Cygnus_Loop_Nebula_crop.jpg/691px-Ultraviolet_image_of_the_Cygnus_Loop_Nebula_crop.jpg" width="100%" /></div></div>
<div id="b"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5b/Ultraviolet_image_of_the_Cygnus_Loop_Nebula_crop.jpg/691px-Ultraviolet_image_of_the_Cygnus_Loop_Nebula_crop.jpg" style="width: 50px; height: 50px" /></div>

#a
{
    float: left;
}

#b
{
    float: right;
}
```

here are two images, floated left and right. When I shrink the width, the right goes under the left - I dont want it. Instead, the left image should shrink.

Comment: Hey @john Smith I submitted this answer below , take a look http://jsfiddle.net/UuwnC/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the css display: table to do that: see [my jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/sV36r/8/)

```
#a
{
    display: table-cell;
}

#b
{
    text-align: right;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#Wrapper
{
    display: table;
}
```

Wrapper div should have a width set on it like on my jsfiddle: -

```
<div id="Wrapper" style="width:100%">
    <div id="a"><div style="max-width: 350px;">
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5b/Ultraviolet_image_of_the_Cygnus_Loop_Nebula_crop.jpg/691px-Ultraviolet_image_of_the_Cygnus_Loop_Nebula_crop.jpg" width="100%" />
    </div>
    <div id="b">
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5b/Ultraviolet_image_of_the_Cygnus_Loop_Nebula_crop.jpg/691px-Ultraviolet_image_of_the_Cygnus_Loop_Nebula_crop.jpg" style="width: 50px; height: 50px" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="maincontainer">


<div id="a"> <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5b/Ultraviolet_image_of_the_Cygnus_Loop_Nebula_crop.jpg/691px-Ultraviolet_image_of_the_Cygnus_Loop_Nebula_crop.jpg" /></div>
<div id="b"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5b/Ultraviolet_image_of_the_Cygnus_Loop_Nebula_crop.jpg/691px-Ultraviolet_image_of_the_Cygnus_Loop_Nebula_crop.jpg" /></div>

</div> 


    #maincontainer {
     width : 600px;
     height : 100px;
     border : solid 2px #0f0f0f;
     }
     #maincontainer img {
        width : 280px;
        height : 80px;
        margin:0 auto;
        display:block;
        background:red;
    }

#a
{
    float: left;
}

#b
{
    float: right;
}
```

HERE IS THE FIDDLE LINK: http://jsfiddle.net/UuwnC/

updated   : http://jsfiddle.net/UuwnC/2/

Comment: PLEASE NOTE TWEAKING THE NUMBERS (width , height )CAN ADJUST to fit your specifications.